# Not able to get the caller information mentioned in the CallKit developer documentation

Tags: ios, callkit

According the the documentation [CallKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit) in the Topic Receiving incoming call it mentions about identifying call and caller and passing that information to a corresponding method.

I tried the same but am not able to get the caller details. Is there any definitive solution for the getting the caller information.

Comment: What call are you talking about?  if you are implementing your own VoIP calling app, then how you get the caller details depends on how your server delivers it to your app. If you are talking about incoming phone calls to the mobile/cellular phone number, you cannot get those call details

Comment: I am talking about the incoming calls to the mobile phone number. Is there no way to get the caller information for that ?

Comment: No, that would be a privacy violation